# ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Здравствуйте. Не запускается springboot приложение. Не могу разобраться почему. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема или хотя бы в какой стороне искать решение. В спринге новичок.
Выдает следующие ошибки:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-10-11
>   22:01:25.731 ERROR 3324 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> 2017-10-11 22:01:25.702  WARN 3324 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

**Консоль**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:2917,suspend=y,server=n -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\ONPU\springboot-kursa\target\classes;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-test-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.2.0\json-path-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.2.1\json-smart-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.1\accessors-smart-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.3\asm-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\2.6.0\assertj-core-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\1.10.19\mockito-core-1.10.19.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.4.0\jsonassert-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-test-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.16\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.16\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.16.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.16\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.9\jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.9\jackson-core-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring4\2.1.5.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\2.1.5.RELEASE\thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.0.8\ognl-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.0.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\nz\net\ultraq\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-layout-dialect\1.4.0\thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy\2.4.12\groovy-2.4.12.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-devtools-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.0.12.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.0.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.0.Final\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.21.0-GA\javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.3.5.Final\hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.3\classmate-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.10\aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\8.5.16\tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\8.5.16\tomcat-juli-8.5.16.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\1.11.6.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.13.6.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.43\mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\4.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\4.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.10.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-taglibs\4.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-taglibs-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Пользователь\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-acl\4.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-acl-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;D:\IdeaUltimate\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.onlineshop.Application
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:2917', transport: 'socket'
22:01:21.236 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
22:01:21.239 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
22:01:21.241 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/D:/ONPU/springboot-kursa/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-10-11 22:01:21.526  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] com.onlineshop.Application               : Starting Application on Пользователь-ПК with PID 3324 (D:\ONPU\springboot-kursa\target\classes started by Пользователь in D:\ONPU\springboot-kursa)
2017-10-11 22:01:21.527  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] com.onlineshop.Application               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-10-11 22:01:21.951  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3e7dc1aa: startup date [Wed Oct 11 22:01:21 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-11 22:01:24.028  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-10-11 22:01:24.043  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-10-11 22:01:24.045  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-10-11 22:01:24.238  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-10-11 22:01:24.239  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2291 ms
2017-10-11 22:01:24.407  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-11 22:01:24.407  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-11 22:01:24.407  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-11 22:01:24.407  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-10-11 22:01:24.408  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-10-11 22:01:24.409  INFO 3324 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-10-11 22:01:25.156  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-10-11 22:01:25.173  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-10-11 22:01:25.246  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-10-11 22:01:25.247  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-10-11 22:01:25.249  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-10-11 22:01:25.291  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-10-11 22:01:25.408  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2017-10-11 22:01:25.702  WARN 3324 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-10-11 22:01:25.706  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-10-11 22:01:25.722  INFO 3324 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-10-11 22:01:25.731 ERROR 3324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.onlineshop.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.onlineshop.model.Product column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:870) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:605) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 27 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:2917', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> q
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.java**

```
    package com.onlineshop;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Структура выглядит следующим образом:

1. Есть контроллер с RequestMapping для index страницы.
2. Есть папка model с файлами entity mapping для бд (hibernate)
3. И папка templates с html страницами в ресурсах.
4. В ресурсах также хранится конфигурационный файл application.properties

Comment: Проблема, похоже, в ваших маппингах, судя по тексту ошибки:  

org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.onlineshop.model.Product column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: приведите листинг сущности com.onlineshop.model.Product

Comment: Прикладываю листинг на Product. https://github.com/Yumika123/onlineshop/blob/codeCorrection/src/main/java/com/onlineshop/model/Product.java

Comment: ссылка не рабочая

Comment: покажи мне код этой таблицы com.onlineshop.model.Product

Comment: Извиняюсь за битую ссылку. Эта 100% рабочая https://github.com/Yumika123/onlineshop/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/onlineshop/model/Product.java